# SFML 2.1 textures

Tags: c++, textures, sfml

I want to see if the texture is bigger than 0 pixels(check if it's displayed) like this:

```
if(image.getSize()>0)
```

Image is a texture.
I get an error saying this:

> error: no match for 'operator>' in 'image.sf::Texture::getSize() > 0'

What does it mean? How can I make it work?(if it's possible)
If it isn't possible, how do I see if the image is there in the texture?
I'm using SFML 2.1, and CodeBlocks.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the way:
Use `if(image.getSize().x>0&&image.getSize().y>0)`
It's comparing the x and y separately.

Answer (score 1):

`sf::Texture::getSize()` returns an `sf::Vector2<T>`, specifically `sf::Vector2u`. You should do

```
sf::Vector2u size = image.getSize();
if(size.x > 0 || size.y > 0) ...
```

or

```
if(image.getSize() > sf::Vector2u(0, 0)) ...
```

Comment: There's no op > for comparing vector; it wouldn't make sense.

Comment: So how should I do it?